# How to iterate on multiple list of objects in jQuery to do a calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Context**: CMPT stands for compte which is Account in english, the application can have multiple accounts which contains an hospitalisation field and for each hospitalisation fields present in ONE account, i want to be able to calculate the `total cost` for each hospitalisations.

Currently i am able to calculate the field `total(mntTotHosp)` which is obtained by doing the calculation of the field `Tarif quotidien ( TariQuoti) * Nombre de jours (NbJrsHosp)` . In english : `Daily price * numbers of days`.

**But this works only for the first Hospitalisation** (ListeHospitalisation[0].mntTotHosp) by doing this :

```js
function CalculMntTotHosp() {
  var tariQuoti = $("input[id$='TariQuoti']").val().replace(",", ".") || 0;
  var nbJrsHosp = $("input[id$='NbJrsHosp']").val().replace(",", ".") || 0;
  var mntTotHosp = tariQuoti * nbJrsHosp
  $("input[id$='MntTotHosp']").val(mntTotHosp.toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
}
```

**My problem :**

I would like to do this for each `CmptETS` in the list `ListeCmptETS` and each `Hospitalisation` contained in `ListeHospitalisation` which is contained in `ListeCmptETS`. Currently it's only able to calculate the total for the first hospitalisation present in the first account.

Here's a screenshot of the 3 fields used to do the calculation, to have a better understanding of the data:
[image]

Sorry the text is in french in the app but here's a visual representation to see the data :

[image]

Hopefully this was enough clear could anyone help ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please remove the screenshots. They're not helpful. Instead, post a snippet of HTML that allows us to see the problem. Use the editor to include jQuery so it works as you see it.

Comment: Use [these instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include the snippet in the question.

Comment: Try using `.each()` to iterate each element in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hard to know what to suggest without seeing more code, but maybe this vanilla-flavored example can get you started:

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".listeCmptETS"));
Array.from(list).forEach((listeCmptETS) => {
  const
    hospSection = listeCmptETS.querySelector(".listeHosp"),
    listeHospitalisation = Array.from(hospSection.querySelectorAll(".stay"));
  listeHospitalisation.forEach((thisStay) => {
    CalculMntTotHosp(thisStay);
  });
});

function CalculMntTotHosp(stay) {
  const
    toNum = (str) => +(str.replace(',', '.') || 0),
    toCurrency = (num) => num.toFixed(2).replace('.', ','),
    tariQuoti = toNum( stay.querySelector('.TariQuoti').value ),
    nbJrsHosp = toNum( stay.querySelector('.NbJrsHosp').value ),
    output = toCurrency(tariQuoti * nbJrsHosp);
  //console.log(`daily: ${tariQuoti}`, `days: ${nbJrsHosp}`);
  stay.querySelector('.MntTotHosp').value = output;
}
```

```css
.listeCmptETS { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
.section { width: 20rem; min-height: 2.5rem; padding-top: 0.4rem; border: 1px solid grey; }
.listeHosp {border-top: none; }
.stay { position: relative; padding: 0.3rem; }
.stay div { margin-bottom: 0.3rem; }
.stay input {display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 3rem; }
```

```html
  <div class="listeCmptETS">
    <div class="section">(non-hospitalization content goes here)</div>
    <div class="listeHosp section">
      <div class="stay">
        <div>Daily<input class="TariQuoti" value="21,00" /></div>
        <div>Days<input class="NbJrsHosp" value="2" /></div>
        <div>Tot<input class="MntTotHosp" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="stay">
        <div>Daily<input class="TariQuoti" value="22,00" /></div>
        <div>Days<input class="NbJrsHosp" value="" /></div>
        <div>Tot<input class="MntTotHosp" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="listeCmptETS">
    <div class="section">(non-hospitalization content goes here)</div>
    <div class="listeHosp section">
      <div class="stay">
        <div>Daily<input class="TariQuoti" value="23,00" /></div>
        <div>Days<input class="NbJrsHosp" value="1" /></div>
        <div>Tot<input class="MntTotHosp" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="stay">
        <div>Daily<input class="TariQuoti" value="24,00" /></div>
        <div>Days<input class="NbJrsHosp" value="3" /></div>
        <div>Tot<input class="MntTotHosp" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```